# Improve themselves

Tags: word-choice

Does "We need to improve ourselves" sound natural or "They want to improve themseves?"

For example, When some people  are selfish, rude, arrogant, etc but they realise they must change they want to be better people. In this case can I say they  want to improve themselves?

Answer (score 0):

They are both completely natural but they are completely different messages communicating completely different things.

Your description does not give information that would let us know what message you are trying to send so we can’t suggest which is better.

Try supplying a lot more context.

Comment: For example, "I know I was not right. I am sorry I was so rude to you. I need to change. I need to improve myself. I don't want to be like that. I don't want you to hate me. I want to change and improve myself."

Comment: That all reads completely fine and natural. Say that:)